# flutter run Error detected in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, testing, runtime-error, pubspec.yaml

when i run the program it shows this following error

```
error on line 43, column 15 of pubspec.yaml: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?
   ╷
43 │   flutter_test:
   │               ^
   ╵
exit code 65

error on line 43, column 15 of pubspec.yaml: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?
   ╷
43 │   flutter_test:
   │               ^
   ╵
exit code 65
```

Comment: Can you include the pubspec.yaml in the question?

Answer (score 0):

this type of errors is usually caused by indentation.YAML relies on proper indentation to define the structure of the document.make sure you are using spaces not tabs and be sure of the level of your content. If you provide the file I may be able to assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

1. step 1 - Make sure that your pubspec.yaml file is properly
   formatted.
2. step 2 -**Indentation**: make sure  the indentation is consistent
3. Definitely **put colons (:)** after each key in the mapping

```html
flutter_test:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

4. **Spacing**: check whether there are any extra spaces or tabs hence **YAML is sensitive** to indentation and spacing